Postgresql PgAgent can't execute Batch Job "Error: Can not open logfile"
We have a Job setup on PGadmin that is being run via PgAgent in linux.
However, when the Job is set as Batch. Even a simple script is getting same error

error message says

Any solution would be a great help, thanks
